# How to correctly and efficiently unwrap these optionals?

Tags: xcode, swift3, sprite-kit, option-type

Yes, it's another optionals question... :(

Every time i think i'm starting to get a good grasp on optionals, Xcode throws me a error fix suggestion for unwrapping.  The following block of code uses all of Xcodes error fixes.  But i dont think it's the correct way of doing this.

```
var btAdd = [SKSpriteNode]()
var btLose = [SKSpriteNode]()

...

let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: pos)

for node in touchedNodes{
    if btAdd.contains((node as? SKSpriteNode)!) {
        let index = Int(String(describing: node.name?[(node.name?.endIndex)!]))
        node.isHidden = true
        btLose[index!].isHidden = false
        var dogTeam = defaults.array(forKey: "dogTeam") as! [Int]
        dogTeam.append(index!)
        defaults.set(dogTeam,forKey: "dogTeam")
    }
}
```

I started to do...

```
if let node as? SKSpriteNode{
   if btAdd.contains(node){
      ...
   }
}
```

But I wasn't sure on that either.

I'm looking for some guidance on the absolute "correct" way to do this block of code.  Not just the `.contains` portion, but the unwrapping of `index` and the UserDefaults array.

Comment: What type is `btAdd` of?

Comment: `[SKSpriteNode]`, bad name, i know.  I'll add the declarations.

Comment: It is simple, if you are 100% sure that optional has its underlying value, then you can use forced unwrapping(on your own responsibility), otherwise you should safely unwrap optional (eg using if let syntax). There is no "right way" and you are in charge to determine how would you use optionals.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the last part of your code seems fine. It's just the first part that needs a bit of tweaking. And the thing that you're "starting to do" is fine as well, but here is another version:

```
for node in touchedNodes where node as? SKSpriteNode != nil &&
    btAdd.contains(node as! SKSpriteNode){
```

If you use the above, you don't even need the if statement in the loop.

You seem to be quite confused with where to force unwrap and where not to. Just remember that you only force unwrap when you are absolutely sure that the thing you're unwrapping cannot be nil.

This line looks quite bad:

```
let index = Int(String(describing: node.name?[(node.name?.endIndex)!]))
```

It seems like you want to get the last character of the node's name and turn it into an int. Since you first checked whether the node is in an array, I think it is safe to force unwrap here. (I assume all the nodes in the array has a name ending with a number) Also, to get the last character, just do `str.character.last`:

```
let index = Int(node.name!.characters.last!.description)!
```

Comment: Yes i agree that line looks ugly, i first tried `.last` with that exact line you have there, but that throws the error _inout String is not convertible to String_.  So i tried other variations of using `characters.last!` but i kept getting different warnings and errors.  One was something like _CharacterView_Element cannot be converted to Int?_, or something along those lines.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup My bad! I missed the `description` there. See the edited answer!

Comment: Beautiful, that works and it's much cleaner than the other way.  I did not know `description` was needed. Thanks for that.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it!

Comment: And your edited `for` loop looks great, makes sense and i would use it, however i need the `if btAdd.contains` in the loop because i have an `else` in there, just didn't post it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap your optionals in an if statement which removes the "optionalness" of them. First example index becomes non optional whenever I reference it

```
    if let index = Int(spinButton.name!) {
        let something = someArray[index]
    }
```

Your way... index2 is always optional every time it gets referenced

```
    let index2 = Int(spinButton.name!)
    let something = someArray[index2!]
```

Comment: Does that really matter if i know that `spinButton.name` will never be nil? Except for that fact of having to use !

Comment: You are misreading this. We are not confirming that spinButton.name is not nil. We are ensuring that index will always have an Int value, and we never have to worry about it later in code or treat it as an optional

Comment: Aren't you kind of doing both?  _if spinButton.name is nil then initialize index as an Int_?

Comment: Never mind, I see it now.  You're ensuring it's a Int value as opposed to a String or something else, correct?

Comment: correct. If you look at your original block of code every time you reference "index" you have to treat it as an optional "index!" , I'm just saying you wrapped those optionals in an if statement you wouldn't have to treat them as optionals later on

Comment: But if I know `.name` will _always_ be an Int, it's acceptable to just do it my way as an optional `index!`?

Comment: Lol, I'm not trying sway you or convince you... in the apple swift book (sorry I don't have a link right now, I'm on my phone)  the book suggests using "if let" to avoid multiple unwrapping of the optional value. I was just answering to your question about efficiently unwrapping optional

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138966/discussion-between-ron-myschuk-and-thevalyreangroup).